# How to connect java with mariaDB localhost via unix soket?

Tags: java, jdbc, mariadb, database-connection

I'm a 2 year teacher of informatics and currently in my second year of teaching but I have little experience in connecting database to java. The school provides a localhost:3306 on its private server with these database specification:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWLlI.jpg)

I can connect a mysql community database from my PC without any problem but I don't know how to approach connecting to the unix socket.

How would i be able to connect the schools database server with a java program.

Comment: Having the database on localhost:3306 suggest you need to connect through TCP/IP, not through a Unix Domain socket. Are you really asking about connecting through a Unix Domain socket, or are you (or your school) mixing up terminology?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the official MariaDB driver, [which can be found here.](https://mariadb.com/downloads/connectors/)

A simple example of this:

```java
import java.sql.*;

public class MyConnector {

public static void connect(String dbLocation, String dbDriver, String user, String password) {
 
     Connection c = null;
     Statement st = null;

    try {

        Class.forName(dbDriver);
        // Connect the driver to your classpath
        c = DriverManager.getConnection(dbLocation, user, password);
        // Now java is connected to the database
        st = c.createStatement();
        
        String changeTable = """
            USE mytable;
            SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = 1;
        """;

        st.executeUpdate(changeTable);
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("[FATAL] Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }


public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        String dbDriver = "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver";
        String user = "root";
        String pass = "root";
        String dbLocation = "jdbc:mariadb://192.168.100.174/db";

    connect(dbLocation, dbDriver, user, root);
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And just to be sure I just need to change the dbLocation ip address to that of the school servers and I'll be set, right?

Comment: @plamen in theory, yes. You also need to change the user, and password, and have the driver installed, etc, but beyond that, I believe so, yes